# TextOut after a click

Tags: winapi

I am just beginning to learn win32 programming. I am trying to do a TextOut() on the screen if the user clicked somewhere in the window. My logic is as follows:

> - On WM_LBUTTONDOWN, set true a "show" variable.
> - On WM_PAINT, TextOut() if "show" is true.

(I could copy the code too if it's needed)

What can possibly go wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not give Windows a reason to generate WM_PAINT. On WM_LBUTTONDOWN you should call InvalidateRect. That tells Windows that a repaint is needed.